# Как поставить такой градиент на текст?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

столкнулся с интересным дизайнерским решением. Текст имеет эффект градиента. Выглядит в макете примерно так , как будто наложили на самого текста такой эффект 
Вот как выглядит слой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как выглядит сам текста с данным эффектом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И текст без градиента
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте для текста такие стили, вроде бы должно Вам подойти, только поиграйтесь немного с градусом наклона (130deg):

```
background: linear-gradient(130deg, #37dfdf 0%, rgb(55, 90, 223) 100%)
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое но как вы поняли что 130 градусов если в Фш там 178

Comment: Обращайтесь.
Я подбирал градусы, примерно, чтобы текст получился такой же как и на прикрепленном Вами скриншоте текста